# Remove row conditionally from data frame

Tags: r

How can I remove rows conditionally from a data table?

For example, I have:

```
Apple, 2001
Apple, 2002
Apple, 2003
Apple, 2004
Banana, 2001
Banana, 2002
Banana, 2003
Candy, 2001
Candy, 2002
Candy, 2003
Candy, 2004
Dog, 2001
Dog, 2002
Dog, 2004
Water, 2002
Water, 2003
Water, 2004
```

Then, I want to include only the rows with 2001-2004 per group, i.e.:

```
Apple, 2001
Apple, 2002
Apple, 2003
Apple, 2004
Candy, 2001
Candy, 2002
Candy, 2003
Candy, 2004
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `data.table`, check `if` all the 2001:2004 are present `%in%` the 'year' column for each group of 'Col1', then get the Subset of Data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, if(all(2001:2004 %in% year)) .SD, by = Col1]
#    Col1 year
#1: Apple 2001
#2: Apple 2002
#3: Apple 2003
#4: Apple 2004
#5: Candy 2001
#6: Candy 2002
#7: Candy 2003
#8: Candy 2004
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("Apple", "Apple", "Apple", "Apple", "Banana", 
"Banana", "Banana", "Candy", "Candy", "Candy", "Candy", "Dog", 
"Dog", "Dog", "Water", "Water", "Water"), year = c(2001L, 2002L, 
 2003L, 2004L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 
 2001L, 2002L, 2004L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L)), .Names = c("Col1", 
 "year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```

Answer (score 2):

With `base R` we can use `ave` to get the desired results

```
df[ave(df$year, df$Col1, FUN = function(x) all(2001:2004 %in% x)) == 1, ]

#   Col1 year
#1  Apple 2001
#2  Apple 2002
#3  Apple 2003
#4  Apple 2004
#8  Candy 2001
#9  Candy 2002
#10 Candy 2003
#11 Candy 2004
```

Answer (score 2):

`dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr) # or library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(Col1) %>% 
    filter(all(2001:2004 %in% year))
```

`. %>% filter(TRUE)` returns all rows, while `. %>% filter(FALSE)` drops all rows of data.

Output:

```
Source: local data frame [8 x 2]
Groups: Col1 [2]

   Col1  year
  <chr> <int>
1 Apple  2001
2 Apple  2002
3 Apple  2003
4 Apple  2004
5 Candy  2001
6 Candy  2002
7 Candy  2003
8 Candy  2004
```